# "Everything is an object", any name for this feature?

Tags: ruby, object, dynamic

In some languages (specially dynamically typed ones), everything , even values, is an object. Like in Ruby you can say:

5.times { do something }

[ 5 is an object, not a primitive, so you can invoke a method (times) on it. ]

Does this language feature has a name on it?

Comment: Pure Object Oriented language, isn't?

Comment: @delnan In most languages (take PHP for example), literal numbers are integers. They are primitives. They are not objects of type Integer or something, so you *can't* say : 6.add(5) and get 11. But in Scala you can say: 6.+(5) and get 11 which is again an object : (6.+(5)).-(3) results in 8 [ roughly ".+()" means ".add()" in Scala ]

Comment: @ashy_32bit: I know. I meant to suggest you simply stick with that phrase. It's well-recognized, relatively well-defined and descriptive.

Comment: @delnan Aha, now it makes perfect sense :)

Answer (score 3):

I think this feature "Everything is an object" appears well in pure/true Object Oriented languages. [Here](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Java_is_pure_object_oriented_language_or_not) is a question about JAVA whether it is a pure OO language or not. I can't find another specific name of "Everything is an object", so I would call it as such.

Comment: apparently EiaO is not enough for a language to be called a pure OOPL but it is indeed necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I know let coin the terms

1. Object Based Language OBL (Ruby...)
2. Object Oriented Language OOL (Java...)
3. Object Extended Language OXL (C++, ObjectiveC...)

What do ya think?  Add a language to each category.

Answer (score 1):

The Ruby Programming Language (co-authored by Matz) describes Ruby as having a "very pure object-oriented programming model".

Note that, in Ruby, not every construct of the syntax is an object.  There are keywords and operators that are neither objects nor methods on objects.  I suspect that this language feature has no glossy name because no language has the feature.

But if you narrow your definition of everything, to every value... Well that's different. :-)